Error en Xampp por cierre inesperado del sistema
Ayuda para revisar este error que arroja XAMPP por cierre inesperado.

InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2024-09-25 14:26:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-09-25 14:26:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-09-25 14:26:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-09-25 14:26:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-09-25 14:26:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-09-25 14:26:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-09-25 14:26:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-09-25 14:26:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2024-09-25 14:26:14 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Are you sure you are using the right ib_logfiles to start up the database? Log sequence number in

the ib_logfiles is 300288, less than the log sequence number in the
first system tablespace file header, 106611077.
2024-09-25 14:26:14 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=7] log sequence number 96184096 is in the future! Current
system log sequence number 300306.
2024-09-25 14:26:14 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log
files. Please refer to
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for
information about forcing recovery.


Este problema suele ocurrir cuando tienes dos instalaciones de MySQL distintas. Lee las respuestas en esta pregunta.

El mensaje te indica que existe un problema con los archivos de registro y el espacio de tablas de innoDB. Tenes que revisar que todos los archivos necesarios para innoDB esten donde tienen que estar.
Si no necesitas los datos en la base de datos y queres reiniciar la instalación tenes que detener MySQL desde XAMPP. Vas al directorio de datos de mysql (puede ser en C:\xampp\mysql\data). Hace una copia de seguridad de tus archivos de datos.
Despues elimina los archivos ib_logfile0 y ib_logfile1 y reinicia mysql. Esto hacd que InnoDB genere nuevos archivos de log.
Si el problema sigue, edita el archivo de configuración my.ini (puede estar en C:\xampp\mysql\bin) y en la seccion [mysqld] agrega esto:
innodb_force_recovery = 1
Reiniciá mysql. Si arranca, exporta tus tablas a un formato como SQL y despues elimina la línea que agregaste y reinicia MySQL de nuevo.
innodb_force_recovery se puede llevar hasta 6 si el 1 no funciona, pero tene cuidado, ya que niveles mas altos pueden generar perdida de datos.
SAludos.
